# How to disable the login password for a specific user?

Tags: 18.04, login, password, budgie

I have two users in my Ubuntu Budgie 18.04.

The first is mine, and the second is for my mother.

I want to disable the login password request from my mother user, so she can log in without the need to remember a password.
I tried simple passwords but the system also don't let me use simple passwords.

I also tried to activate the auto login, but it is annoying when I turn on my laptop to use My account, and it will log into my mother's user, and I need to log off to enter into mine.

The guest user also doesn't work, when I try to log in, it will go back to the login screen.

Comment: Looking through logfiles, I found this (logged by `lightdm`): `pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "walt"` (I use a password). Try adding your Mom to the `nopasswdlogin` group (`sudo adduser Mom nopasswdlogin`). Untested, might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through logfiles, I found this (logged by `lightdm`): `pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "walt"` (I use a password). Try adding your Mom to the `nopasswdlogin` group (`sudo adduser Mom nopasswdlogin`). Untested, might work.

Comment: I got `adduser: The group `nopasswdlogin' does not exist.`

Answer (score 4):

1.To keep a small password.

Change password on terminal `sudo passwd username`
Enter whatever small password you like at prompt "Enter new UNIX password:"

And again type at prompt "Retype new UNIX password:"

Note: on terminal you will not see anything when you type the password.

2. To make totally password free:

   **Run very carefully:**

   ```
   sudo -H gedit /etc/sudoers
   ```

   add

   ```
   <username>   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
   ```

   below the line

   ```
   %sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
   ```

   save and close.

and also:

Delete password for user:

```
sudo passwd -d <username>
```

Repeat the steps for other user.

3. To add to the group nopasswdlogin:

   `sudo usermod -a -G nopasswdlogin <USERNAME>`
4. To remove from nopasswdlogin group:

   `sudo gpasswd -d <USERNAME> nopasswdlogin`

Comment: Please note it is best to do `sudo -H gedit /etc/sudoers`!!!

Comment: Won't this simply let the OP's mom issue `sudo any_command` without a password? If I got that right, this is not what the OP asked for.

Comment: ... even better than `sudo -H gedit /etc/sudoers` IMHO would be `sudo visudo` (or `sudo -H VISUAL=gedit visudo` if you insist on using `gedit`) however I agree with @PerlDuck this doesn't seem to be what the OP is looking for